# how to add height and width to highchart dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular5, highcharts

I am using `angular-highcharts`, in this we have options like `addSeries(), removeSeries(), addPoint()` etc. but nothing like add height and width.
In `angular-highchart`, there are some issues that if I'm working with `widgets` having full screen option. When the widget goes `fullscreen` inside which the `highchart` is there, the `highchart` doesn't take the parent height and width i.e. Widget's height and width.

Normally, I can give height and width like this:

```
chart:{
   type:'bar',
   height:600,
   width:1450
},
```

So, is there any solution that how I can add height and width dynamically in `highcharts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no setHeight or setWidth but there is a setSize:

setSize( [width] [, height] [, animation]). Example:

```
chart.setSize(chartWidth, chartHeight);
```

here is an jsfiddle testing setSize

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-setsize-button/

also there is an 'update' function where you can update almost every option of the chart, here is an jsfiddle showing how:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-update/

Comment: @LPZadikel You are right but I'm using a package for highcharts in angular 5 i.e. angular-highchart, in this no such method is available.

Comment: in that case you may want to render again the chart with new chart options